# Saving data from a form back to an object

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I can create an object and then bind data to my asp.net web form fairly easily by doing this:

Code behind:

```
Car = CarFactory.GetCar(CInt(_carID))
Page.DataBind()
```

And on my web form:

```
asp:Label ID="lblParts" runat="server" Text='<%# Car.PartsList%>' />
```

I was wondering if there is a related method to take the data from the web form and then update the object without having to do a bunch of:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCarName.Text) Then Car.DisplayName = tbCarName.Text
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Modelbinding** and in fact since ASP.NET 4.5 there is this capability in Webforms as well. It only works with special databound controls like GridView though, not simple TextBoxes.

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetwebforms45_topic2#_Toc318982797

Comment: Oh ok, so for simpler controls, like labels, I have to do it manually like I stated above?

Comment: There is no point in modelbinding to labels, because their content does not change. And to bind a single object property to a Textbox, you would have to do it manually, yes. Or you write your own class that inherits from textbox and do the modelbinding yourself.

Comment: what about drop down lists where the user can select different values?  -Thanks